# PROGMEM variable discarded even if declared as (used)

Tags: c, linker, avr-gcc, atmelstudio, progmem

I'm using ATMEL Studio 6.2 and its toolchain with avr-gcc (avr8-gnu-toolchain). I have a variable that needs to be placed in flash (PROGMEM) and I declare it as a global:

```
static const uint16_t gPrgLen PROGMEM __attribute__((used)) = 0;
```

The compiler doesn't complain and the linker doesn't complain, but when I open the .lss file, there is no gPrgLen to be found. In the .map file we can see that it has been listed under "discarded input sections"

```
Discarded input sections
.progmem.data.gPrgLen    0x00000000    0x2    Boot.o
```

It is built as a release, but a debug build gives the same result.
How can I force the linker to include this variable in the `*(.progmem*)` section?

EDIT
Added `static` but still the same result.

Here is the linker part:

```
# All Target
all: $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES)

$(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH): $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(OUTPUT_FILE_DEP) $(LIB_DEP)
@echo Building target: $@
@echo Invoking: AVR/GNU Linker : 4.8.1
$(QUOTE)C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.1056\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe$(QUOTE) -o$(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH_AS_ARGS) $(OBJS_AS_ARGS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map="Boot.map" -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-lm  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-section-start=.text=0xf800  -mmcu=at90usb647  
@echo Finished building target: $@
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.1056\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-objcopy.exe" -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock -R .signature -R .user_signatures  "Boot.elf" "Boot.hex"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.1056\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-objcopy.exe" -j .eeprom  --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --change-section-lma .eeprom=0  --no-change-warnings -O ihex "Boot.elf" "Boot.eep" || exit 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.1056\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-objdump.exe" -h -S "Boot.elf" > "Boot.lss"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.1056\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-objcopy.exe" -O srec -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock -R .signature -R .user_signatures "Boot.elf" "Boot.srec"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.1056\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-size.exe" "Boot.elf"
```

Comment: have you tried this line `(void)PROGMEM;` somewhere in your code to force usage of the variable? if it doesn't work, then you have to force it in the linker file (do you have a linker file ?)

Comment: I have tried to use the variable in the program, but it's still not linked. ATMEL Studio is generating the make file, but I can set "free" options in the project properties.

Comment: can you post the linker part of the makefile?

Comment: Updated with makefile linker section.

Comment: Are you using `avr-g++`?  Try putting `extern "C"` at the very beginning of the line defining the PROGMEM variable, to tell the compiler not the mangle its name.

Answer (score 0):

Odd that `__attribute__((used))` isn't working. Two suggestions to try.

First, change the variable from `static` to `volatile` (or just add `volatile`). That *may* prevent it from being optimized away.

If that doesn't work, instead you can add a line to the linker to make it "[p]retend the symbol *symbol* is undefined, to force linking of library modules to define it" ([GCC Link Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-u)). This is done via `-u symbol` or `--undefined=symbol`.

To add it to the Atmel Studio project file, go to Toolchain -> AVR/GNU Linker -> Miscellaneous. Then in Other Linker Flags add `--undefined=gPrgLen`.

I've used this to embed revision/compile-time information into the Hex file where it wasn't otherwise used. That way I could retrieve the memory from a device and know under what conditions it was built (primarily for tracking changes during prototyping and initial firmware debugging). My main.c file had a global char array that looked something like `const char codeCompileDetails[] PROGMEM = "company_name-" __DATE__ "-" __TIME__;`. Coupled with `--undefined=codeCompileDetails`, that data (here including the date and time the code was compiled) always makes it into the executable.